# Extjs 3.3.1 isn't displaying errors

Tags: javascript, extjs, error-handling, firebug

Is there an option somewhere to enable the displaying of errors in Extjs 3, for debugging purposes. Because whenever something fails it doesn't seem to display an error message in firebug.

I'm more familiar with jQuery and it's error handler.

Comment: I have noticed that occasionally FireBug will stop displaying error messages. Restarting FF usually helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal but I have found that Chrome will display the error and the call stack

Answer (score 0):

You need include ext-all-debug.js file instead of ext-all.js.
Of course you also need to use firebug!

Comment: I am currently using ext-all-debug.js and firebug

Comment: So you need give us more examples for this part: _something fails it doesn't seem to display an error message_